# Xamarin WebRTC in IOS WebView not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, webrtc-ios

I'm trying to integrate webrtc into Xamarin Forms app using webview
Android is working fine but in IOS streaming camera not working . I think the problem in IOS WebView render here's my render

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer, IWKScriptMessageHandler
    {
        public HybridWebViewRenderer() : this(new WKWebViewConfiguration())
        {
        }

        public HybridWebViewRenderer(WKWebViewConfiguration config) : base(config)
        {
            config.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
            userController = config.UserContentController;
            var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
            userController.AddUserScript(script);
            userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "invokeAction");
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                userController.RemoveAllUserScripts();
                userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler("invokeAction");
                GenericWebView hybridWebView = e.OldElement as GenericWebView;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup();
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                //{((GenericWebView)Element).Uri}
                string filename = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, $"/test.html");
                LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(filename, false)));
            }
        }

        public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
        {
            ((GenericWebView)Element).InvokeAction(message.Body.ToString());
        }

       
    }
```

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, please check the two permissions camera and photo permission in your `info.plist` : `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`, `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`.

**And then**,you could manage to replace `WkWebViewRenderer` by `ViewRenderer` and set `AllowsInlineMediaPlayback`.

```
 using WebKit;
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
 namespace WebViewRendererDemo.iOS
 {
     public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>
     {
         WKWebView wkWebView;
         protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
         {
             base.OnElementChanged(e);
             if (Control == null)
             {
                 WKWebViewConfiguration configuration = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                 configuration.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
                 wkWebView = new WKWebView(new CGRect(0,0,300,400), configuration);
                 wkWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(xxxx);
                 SetNativeControl(wkWebView);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Not Working , I've upload the Sample here , Working in Android Only . Your solution make the webview elements disappear in the inspector 
https://github.com/amrkamal1993/XamarinWebRTC

Comment: Here are some suggestions: 1. Update VS(for mac/windows) to the latest 2.Uninstall the app from your device 3. Delete bin and obj and rebuild it.